# Model evaluation using R2 and RMSE

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am developing a machine learning model to predict the energy of a molecule ($E$). $R^2$ and $RMSE$ (root mean squared error) values I am getting for the prediction of $ln(E+5)$ are .71 and .08.

I know $R^2$ is not good enough. Based on $RMSE$, can my model be considered a good one?

Comment: There's no way for anyone to provide a useful answer to this question. You need to give some detail as to what you are doing and the nature/units of the data you're working with. That aside, statistics like the ones you mention (I'm assuming these are computed on out-of-sample data) are only useful on a relative basis; they can tell you if the model is performing better than some competing method of prediction, but by themselves they are almost useless. On the other hand, if those metrics are computed in-sample, they aren't even useful for comparing the model to other candidate models.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that in the natural sciences, there is very often an a priori sense of the functional form of the predictor-response relationship, and in such situations a machine learning (functional form agnostic, nonparametric, etc.) approach is not appropriate. This is where simply stating your problem is more useful than asking for help solving it in a particular way. Automotive analogy: asking for someone to help you tighten head bolts with an impact wrench (you're supposed to use a torque wrench!).

Answer (score 3):

There are no hard and fast rules on what a "good" model is. It all depends on the subject you are investigating. The weather in 10 seconds is easy to predict, the weather in a week is very difficult to predict and the weather in a year's time is considered impossible to predict.

So $R^2 = 0.71$ would probably considered to be a very "bad" model for the weather in 10 seconds but revolutionary good for the weather in a year from now.

If $RSME = 0.8$ is to be considered mediocre, good or fantastic depends on what you are predicting based on which data and can only be answered by someone knowing about the energy of molecules under certain conditions, not by a statistician.